# Packager forgot my files

Tags: packages

I am trying to prepare a package with some doc (PDF) inside. Here is basically what I did.

```
bzr whoami "[xxx]"
cd ~/Documents/src
tar cvzf makenator-doc-3rdparty_1.0.1.tar.gz makenator-doc-3rdparty
mv makenator-doc-3rdparty_*.tar.gz ~/Packages
cd ~/Packages
bzr dh-make makenator-doc-3rdparty 1.0.1 makenator-doc-3rdparty_1.0.1.tar.gz
cd makenator-doc-3rdparty
rm debian/*.ex debian/*.EX debian/README.*
vi debian/*
bzr add debian/source/format
bzr add debian/source
bzr add debian
bzr commit -m "Initial commit of 3rd party doc packaging 1.0.1."
bzr builddeb -- -us -uc
cd ..
scp * [xxx]:/Archive/mini-dinstall/incoming
```

All works, except that the .deb is 1416 bytes... and my makenator-doc-3rdparty_1.0.1.tar.gz is 1836556 bytes.

Any clue of what I missed?

Update #1:

Here is my file tree:

```
.
├── configure
├── debian
│   ├── changelog
│   ├── compat
│   ├── control
│   ├── copyright
│   ├── docs
│   ├── rules
│   ├── rules.dh7
│   └── source
│       └── format
├── 1.pdf
└── 2.pdf
```

Comment: have you tried to take a look into your deb-file? I beleive it is empty...

Comment: it is empty for sure, but why? Do I need to explicitely list the files or put them in a specific place?

Comment: yes you should add list

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyVesnin, but how do I do that? I updated my post with the tree.

Comment: Is it working now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start [here at the official docs](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial) and [this official tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging) - for your project I do recommend you to write a small makefile to facilitate corresponding targets like `install` *and*`debian/install` file. You can start [right here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/index.en.html) if you're not a newbie with Debian packaging, otherwise *please take your time starting your reading from links I provided above*